# Views duplicate result if multiple entity reference

Tags: views, entities

case: I have 2 content types A & B and there is field in B which is entity reference of A and this field can hold multiple values from A "Multiple Values",
so i created view to show records from B and i added some fields from A based on relation i made in the view "Entity Referenced", the problem is i get duplicated result if this field has multiple values even if i checked distinct in the view.

so is there direct way to solve it, or i have to fix it with custom code in custom module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out good solution which is as follow:
-A is the content type & B is the second content type
-A is field entity reference in the content type of A with multiple values.
-in the views in creating view of content type B just render the field of entity reverence A normally, by default it will render the title whether its 1 value or more. 
-now the views for this field in formatter option choose Rendered Entity.
-and in view mode we can choose Tokens.
-now we got to the content type A and then go to manage display tab.
-at the bottom left in the menu click on Custom display settings and then check the option Tokens and click save.
-now in the top right tab "Tokens" display will appear, click on it.
-now we choose which field we want to appear in the view & we can control the label, value, the format. for my case i just showed 1 field without the label and with plain text format and thats was great enough with out making relation and duplicate the content.

Comment: You have to delete the relationship to get rid of the duplicate rows.

Comment: This isn't a good solution if you want to use fields, and doesn't actually deal with the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as my understanding this duplicated results are actually not duplicated :)

**let's say we have two type:**

- content type is the cities    (type B in your question)
- content type is the employees (type A in your question

**so, that means the view will look like**

- Jorge lives in Washington
- Ali   lives in Cairo
- Hana  lives in Washington

we can see here the Washington is not really duplicated because each one related the different employee

**the general solution is the grouping like the following**

**Washington** : Jorge  + Hana
**Cairo**      : Ali

if this is really your case,, i advice you to read this [post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1587834)

Comment: While insightful, this answer doesn't actually provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the records actually *are* distinct from a database perspective as there are multiple records generated by different entity references.

The Drupal 8 core issue for this is [Views relationships with multi-valued entity reference fields invalidate Distinct query option](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2993688).  There should be usable patches there.

For Drupal 7, use the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module as [it probably won't be fixed in Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2976266).